# Key-value lookup system in Latex macros fails if value has latex tokens

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I am trying to use a sort of key-value lookup system in a LaTeX document, but I am having problems when the value itself has LaTeX code within it. In my document, I have the following macro definitions:

```latex
\makeatletter
\def\NewLabel#1#2{\expandafter\xdef\csname LBL@#1\endcsname{#2}}

\def\Ref#1{\@ifundefined{LBL@#1}{???}{\csname LBL@#1\endcsname}}
```

With these macros, I can do the following in my document:

```latex
\NewLabel{name1}{John Smith}

\begin{document}
\Ref{name1}
\end{document}
```

However, the following fails complaining about an extra `}`:

```latex
\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewLabel{name1}{\href{mailto:johnsmith@exmaple.com}{John Smith}}

\begin{document}
\Ref{name1}
\end{document}
```

I know the solution has to have something to do with `\protect` or `\relax` or something like that, but I can't figure out what it is.

Does anyone know the solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I found two solutions to my problem, one using `\noexpand` and the other changing `\xdef` to `\gdef`, though I must admit that I do not fully understand the consequences of my solutions (particularly the use of `\gdef`). The more narrow solution using `\noexpand` is:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\NewLabel#1#2{\expandafter\xdef\csname LBL@#1\endcsname{#2}}

\def\Ref#1{\@ifundefined{LBL@#1}{???}{\csname LBL@#1\endcsname}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewLabel{name1}{\noexpand\href{mailto:johnsmith@exmaple.com}{John Smith}}

\begin{document}
\Ref{name1}
\end{document}
```

The wider solution using `\gdef` is:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\NewLabel#1#2{\expandafter\gdef\csname LBL@#1\endcsname{#2}}

\def\Ref#1{\@ifundefined{LBL@#1}{???}{\csname LBL@#1\endcsname}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\NewLabel{name1}{\href{mailto:johnsmith@exmaple.com}{John Smith}}

\begin{document}
\Ref{name1}
\end{document}
```

Though I see why using `\gdef` instead of `\xdef` will avoid expanding the argument, which was previously causing the problem, I am not sure what negative consequences this could have. Is there a context where the change from `\xdef` to `\gdef` could cause problems?